# Unable to create postgis extension into postgres docker's image

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create postgis extension into postgres docker image.
Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6.4

RUN apt-get clean \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install postgis \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./scripts/postgis.sh  /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgis.sh
```

postgis.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
for DB in $(psql -t -c  "SELECT datname from pg_database where datname = 'backend'"); do
    echo "Loading PostGIS extensions into $DB"
    "${psql[@]}" --dbname="$DB" <<-'EOSQL'
        CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
EOSQL
done
```

I configure the `user` and `password` into a file.yaml. I can access to the database however the extension was not created. 
I followed some solutions mentioned in some questions which are similar to this question but they didn't solve my problem. What's the fault that I commited or missed?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you run the container?

Comment: what is the error message? Have you installed the scripts `postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4-scripts`?

Comment: @larsks I don't get any error message

Comment: @JimJones I didnt install it I just add the command `apt-get -y install postgis` in Docjkerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `postgis` package you've installed doesn't actually include the `postgis` extension. The contents of that package are:

```
root@934775e6cf67:/# dpkg -L postgis
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/raster2pgsql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/shp2pgsql.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/pgsql2shp.1.gz
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/postgis
/usr/share/doc/postgis/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgis/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgis/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/postgis/copyright
/usr/share/doc/postgis/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/postgis-doc
/usr/share/doc/postgis-doc/README.postgis.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/pgsql2shp
/usr/bin/raster2pgsql
/usr/bin/shp2pgsql
```

So those are support tools for `postgis`, but not the extension itself. You need to install the `postgresql-9.6-postgis-2.4` package.  Once this is installed, I can successfully run the `create extension postgis` command.

Comment: I try to install it and I will inform you.